# how to share content in fragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android

please am sorry to ask this simple question, but have been battling with this problem for the past one week. I will appreciate if anyone can solve this problem for me by coding inside the onclick of the button listener which when clicked it share the content in the fragment or the adapter that extends fragmentStatePageAdapter.

**My Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final Adapter devicePageAdaptor = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(devicePageAdaptor);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
}
```

**The Fragment**

```
public class fragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ProverbKey = "proverbKey" ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_device, container, false);


        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        if (bundle != null) {
            String proverb = bundle.getString(ProverbKey);


            setValues(view,proverb);

        }
        return view;
    }

    private void setValues(View view, String proverb) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_proverb);
        textView.setText(proverb);



    }

}
```

**The Adapter that extends fragmentStateAdapter**

```
public class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    String[] proverb;


    public Adapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm,Context context) {
        super(fm);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        proverb = resources.getStringArray(R.array.proverb);

    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(fragment.ProverbKey, proverb[position]);

        fragment deviceFragment = new fragment();
        deviceFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return deviceFragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return proverb.length;
    }
}
```

**And my String Array in each fragment which is named proverb**

```
<string-array name="proverb">
    <item>A young idler, an old beggar.</item>
    <item>Action speaks louder than words.</item>
    <item>A hungry man is an angry man.</item>
    <item>A living dog is better than a dead lion.</item>
    <item>A hedge between keeps friendship green.</item>
    <item>A heavy purse gives to a light heart.</item>
    <item>A handful of patience is worth more than a bushel of brains</item>
    <item>A guilty conscience needs no accuser.</item>
    <item>A growing youth has a wolf in his belly.</item>
    <item>A good name is better than a good face.</item>
    <item>A good beginning makes a good end.</item>
    <item>A drop of ink may make a million think.</item>
    <item>A dry March, a wet April and a cool May may fill barn and cellar and bring much hay.</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: what you want to achieve onclick of button?

Comment: in the fragment what you want show , and what onclick is suppose to do ?

Comment: in onclick, i want to be able to share each string  in the array because each string already show in each fragment using fragmentStatePageAdapter

Comment: You mean Share External like Facebook Whatsaap etc.

Comment: if you want that its simple i will help you.

Comment: yes...please help me out

Comment: Ok wait a second i will post the on click code

Comment: Check it man if helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Global Variable
  String[] proverb;
 //Init on onCreate()
proverb = resources.getStringArray(R.array.proverb);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            String itemToShare = proverb[pos];
            share(itemToShare);

        }
    });

    private void share(String item) {
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, item);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Sharing Item!"));

}
```

Try this and update me if works

Comment: saved your another week accept the answer and vote it up kidding never mind cheers!